# Login en distintas pestañas

Tags: asp.net

Ojala me puedan ayudar, necesito crear un Login en ASP.NET el cual sea capaz unicamente de mantener 1 sesion activa.

Actualmente logro mantener 1 sesion por navegador por el ID de sesion pero el problema que tengo es que si abro una pestaña el mismo me permite ingresar ya que comparten el mismo ID de session.

Existe alguna manera de restringirlo por pestaña?

Agradezco su ayuda,

sls.

Comment: No estoy seguro de lo que deseas implementar, si es evitar que un usuario abra otra pestaña cuando ha hecho sesión o si quieres que se pueda abrir otra sesión en el mismo navegador usando otra pestaña. Si es lo primero, creo que deberías pensar mejor en la lógica de tu aplicación, no conozco ningún caso en los que eso sea un problema, a menos que la aplicación tenga un problema para manejar tal situación.

Comment: Tienes razón yo mismo lo considero ilógico dado que si el navegador está abierto y está logueado en una.pestaña será la.misma persona la que utilize dicha sesión. Solo que el cliente lo requiere así :/